# free line drawing on tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to understand the following piece of Tkinter code that allows a user to freely draw on the canvas using the computer's mouse. I was however unable to understand what the following line of code is actually doing.

```
prev = move_event
```

here is the complete code ...

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(master, width=600, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.pack(padx=20, pady=20)


def click(click_event):
    global prev
    prev = click_event


def move(move_event):
    global prev
    canvas.create_line(prev.x, prev.y, move_event.x, move_event.y, width=2)
    prev = move_event  # what does this do ?


canvas.bind('<Button-1>', click)
canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', move)

mainloop()
```

Comment: It saves the current event into a global variable.

Comment: It is just making a ton of tiny lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the click function, a global variable is used to store the initial mouse click. The same variable is used in the move function as a reference to the starting point of the line being drawn. As the user moves the mouse the move function gets called repeatedly and the drawing continues from the last previous point (prev = move_event). When the user releases the mouse click and then re-clicks, the process begins again with the click function storing the initial point.